# Odoo13-CE: Error message: The requested operation ("read" to "account" (account.account)) was rejected due to following rules: Account multi-company

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-13

Module Invoicing: I wanted to set Fiscal Localization Package and got the following error message:

```
The requested operation ("read" to "account" (account.account)) was rejected due to the following rules:
- Account multi-company
```

Note: This could be a multi-company problem

```
(Records: 2000 domestic partner receivables without own debtor account (id=68), User: Test (id=27))
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you looked into the rule? If yes, did you check the data against the rule and the access settings of user "Test"?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in User: Test (id=27), it seems like the Test user does not have access to a specific company, you should check the allowed company in user form view.